# Android UI Activity will not change to Landscape

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation

I have an Activity (activity_main.xml - only Activity in app) for vertical orientation and added the layout-land to the res directory with the same named xml.  However, when I change the orientation of the phone to landscape the new screen is not created/substituted.  Sure I am missing something really simple but cannot find it... any ideas?

Comment: Sorry for this silly question, but does your phone actually change it's orientation on rotation? it could be that you disabled this feature and forgot to put it on...

Comment: <embarrassed>NOT a silly question at all - yep the test one DID have the screen lock on inadvertently... BIG THANKS</embarrassed>

Comment: You're welcome... and it's no big deal... happens with everybody ;)

Comment: However, still not loading the other activity view though now the screen is switching and the onConfigurationChanged is being fired... ugh...

Comment: Try to remove `configChanges` from the manifest... this flag shows to the system that you're Activity will handle the changes by it self...
Actually it's quite strange by default if you have defined the two files in `/layout` and `/layout-land` it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest file put this code in your Activity Tag

```
 android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

Edited :
changing orientation :
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

and add this code to your Manifest file:

```
android:configChanges = "orientation"
```

Comment: Sorry - I meant I want it to alter back and forth between the 2 based upon change of the user changing the phone... its not doing that but rather showing the same whether the user holds it vertically or in landscape

Comment: Where do I put the " setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

Answer (score 0):

add this to your activity in manifest file

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

and following in your activity

```
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config) {

        super.onConfigurationChanged(config);
}
```

Comment: The onConfigurationChanged is being fired, but is still not switching to the other view. If I set the manifest for the view to android:screenOrientation="landscape" then it does show (and is locked) so I've got the layout right I think, but it is not switching when orientation changes.